# Error when using equations and mathescape in source codes using the listings package

Tags: listings, r

I want to write equations within source code that i formatted with the listings package. Therefore I use `mathescape=true`.

The strange thing is, that it only works when I change the language of my listing to `bash` (there might be others), but not when it is set to `R`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{keywordstyle=\textbf}
\lstset{commentstyle=\textcolor{red}}

\begin{document}

\lstset{language=R}
\begin{lstlisting}[
    frame=trBL,mathescape=true,
    caption={R-Code (test).},
    label={code:R_allee}
]
# comment
square <- function(x) {
    x^2
    % $x^{2}$
}

# nerv
x <- c(1:100)
y <- square(x)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}​
```

There I get the error:

```
 ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
```

I can't find my mistake, since this happens when I exchange `bash` by `R` (without setting any brace).

Does anyone of you have an idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to modify the escape character, since **R** uses `$` as part of its special characters/notation - one motivation as to why a switch to `bash` works. To use a different escape character, add the option `escapechar=|` to the listing to escape between `|...|`. Consequently, the following should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{keywordstyle=\textbf}
\lstset{commentstyle=\textcolor{red}}

\begin{document}

\lstset{language=R}
\begin{lstlisting}[
    frame=trBL,escapechar=|,
    caption={R-Code (test).},
    label={code:R_allee}
]
# comment
square <- function(x) {
    x^2
    % |$x^{2}$|
}

# nerv
x <- c(1:100)
y <- square(x)
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}​
```

[image: Escaping to math in R listing]

Note that once you escape, you need to use `$...$` again to provide the command in LaTeX math mode, as I've done in the above example. See the [`listings` package document](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) Section **4.14 Escaping to LaTeX** for more on this and what other escaping options are available.